# JoinAcross datasets based on Equal and not on SameQ

Tags: dataset, conditional

JoinAcross will join keys if values are the same (SameQ==True) but not if there are equal.
For example these two associations are not joined :

`JoinAcross[{<|a -> 1, b -> X|>}, {<|a -> 1., c -> Y|>}, Key[a]]`

Does it exist a way to simply join across datasets based on equal values with keeping the left or right value?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe `Merge[{<|a -> 1, b -> X|>, <|a -> 1., c -> Y|>}, First]` or `Merge[{<|a -> 1, b -> X|>, <|a -> 1., c -> Y|>}, Last]`?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. Try an answer for      JoinAcross[{<|a -> 1, b -> X|>, <|a -> 2, b -> XX|>, <|a -> 3, 
   b -> XXX|>}, {<|a -> 1, c -> Y|>, <|a -> 2, c -> YY|>, <|a -> 3, 
   c -> YYY|>}, Key[a]] with replacing for example '1' with '1.'

Comment: Or by just applying `N` onto the input? `data = {
   {<|a -> 1, b -> X|>, <|a -> 2, b -> XX|>, <|a -> 3, b -> XXX|>}, {<|
     a -> 1., c -> Y|>, <|a -> 2, c -> YY|>, <|a -> 3,
      c -> YYY|>}
   };
JoinAcross[Sequence @@ N@data, Key[a]]`

Comment: Some of my values are numerical values, other are dateobjects not in the same timezone so I am looking for a general method to JoinAcross based on equal values and not same values.

Comment: Just a minor correction for my last example : JoinAcross[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> X|>, <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> XX|>, <|
   "a" -> 3, "b" -> XXX|>}, {<|"a" -> 1, "c" -> Y|>, <|"a" -> 2, 
   "c" -> YY|>, <|"a" -> 3, "c" -> YYY|>}, "a"]

Comment: Hm. Many set related functions have an option `SameTest`, but `JoinAcross` does not, unfortunately.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, I think `Merge` has the same issue. Have you tested your first comment?

Comment: If you suspect that only the "a" have an integer or real value, then pursuing Henrik idea, you may initialy only convert those to become reals. `Query[All, {"a" -> N}]@ {<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> X|>, <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> XX|>, <|"a" -> 3, 
  "b" -> XXX|>}`

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tested this function very thoroughly yet, but I think this should get you started. The idea is to go through one of the lists and replace the elements on the joining key with elements "projected" on the elements from the other list (under the specified sametest). After that, I think you should be able to use the regular `JoinAcross`:

```
joinAcross2[
   list1 : {__?AssociationQ},
   list2 : {__?AssociationQ},
   sameTest_,
   key : (_String | _Key),
   jspec : ("Inner" | "Outer" | "Left" | "Right") : "Inner"
] := Module[{
    vals1 = list1[[All, key]]
   },
   JoinAcross[
    list1,
    MapAt[
     Function[
      element,
      SelectFirst[vals1, sameTest[element, #] &, element]
     ],
     list2,
     {All, key}
    ],
    key,
    jspec
   ]
];
```

As you can see, I've only implemented this for joining on a single key.

Test:

```
In[208]:= joinAcross2[{<|a -> 1, b -> X|>}, {<|a -> 1., c -> Y|>}, Equal, Key[a]]

Out[208]= {<|a -> 1, b -> X, c -> Y|>}
```

*edit*
Performance:

If the computation time is prohibitive, you can try to rewrite the `MapAt` function inside if that's the limiting step. Right now, we map over the column of a list of associations. You could instead try to compute the column values first and use in-place assignment to modify the original dataset. So we'd replace the `MapAt` with something like:

```
Module[{dataset = list2},
 dataset[[All, key]] = Map[
   Function[element, 
     SelectFirst[vals1, sameTest[element, #] &, element]
   ],
   dataset[[All, key]]
 ];
 dataset
]
```

However, this will only be worthwhile if your `sameTest` can be compiled. If that's the case, the `Map` should be pretty fast. Try using `Compile` to see if you can get a compiled version of `Function[element, ...]`.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help. It does the job. The only drawaback is the computation time which is very high for large datasets.

Comment: I added a suggestion for improving the computation time. However, I would recommend you first do a sanity check to see what's the limiting step in your computation: the inner `MapAt` or the outer `JoinAcross`.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I have tested and this is the MapAt function which is very very slow. The issue is I have dateobjects with timezone inside the sameTest (equal test for my case where I wan't to joinacross some datasets with dateobjets not in the same timezone) so I don't know if it is possible to compile such a test with dateobjects?

Comment: You certainly can't compile `DateObject`s, but you could try to rewrite your `sameTest` using `AbsoluteTime`. Often that speeds things up quite a bit. In the worst case scenario, you'll have to convert all date objects to numbers with `AbsoluteTime` and convert them back afterwards. You might also try using `Dataset` to see if that improves the speed of the mapping.